# Convert from VisonKit RecognizedItem bounds to view bounds

Tags: ios, visionkit, datascannerviewcontroller

I'm trying to implement custom highlight views for iOS 16 `DataScannerViewController`. So far I can add the subviews to the overlayContainerView but I'm struggling with converting from the item bounds to the view bounds.

```
    func dataScanner(_ dataScanner: DataScannerViewController, didUpdate updatedItems: [RecognizedItem], allItems: [RecognizedItem]) {
        for item in updatedItems {
            if let view = parent.itemHighlightViews[item.id] {
                    
                    view.bounds = item.bounds //Cannot assign value of type 'RecognizedItem.Bounds' to type 'CGRect'
                
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I position my highlight views correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, in my head I overcomplicated it and the solution is pretty straight forward:

```
let rect = CGRect(origin: item.bounds.bottomLeft,
                  size: CGSize(width: item.bounds.topRight.x - item.bounds.topLeft.x,
                               height: item.bounds.topRight.y - item.bounds.bottomRight.y))

view.frame = rect
```